# wait for the result of an http request and do something based on the result

Tags: angular, http, frontend

i need to make an **http request** for add something in a database and add in the front end, i need to **know if a request is completed without error or is ok**, and if the request **is ok add to database the value**, on **error i want to break**, i have tryed to use the **(error)** function but the value is always undefined.
sorry for my bad english.

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component, Inject, Injectable, Input, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialogRef} from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { JsonTableComponent } from "../json-table/json-table.component";
import {MAT_DIALOG_DATA} from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { DataSource } from '@angular/cdk/collections';
import { NumberFormatStyle } from '@angular/common';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-menu-modifica',
  templateUrl: './menu-modifica.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./menu-modifica.component.css']
})
export class MenuModificaComponent implements OnInit {




constructor(private http: HttpClient,
  private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<MenuModificaComponent>,
  @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: number,  
  ) {}



  name: any;
  weight: any;
  position: any;
  symbol: any;

  ngOnInit(): void {


  }

   async modifica(){
   let result = await this.modifyRecord(this.data, this.name, this.weight, this.symbol)
   this.dialogRef.close()
  }

  async modifyRecord(id: any, name: any, weight: Number, symbol: any){
    let url = `http://127.0.0.1:5000/change`
    
      if(name === undefined){
        console.log("Il nome non c'è")
        console.log()
      }


    this.http.patch(url, {id: id, name: name, weight: weight, symbol: symbol}).subscribe((res: any) => {
      console.log(url)
      console.log(res)
      },
      (error)=>{console.log("ERRORE OBSERVABLE")},
      () => console.log("FINITA")
      )
    
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

use the beauty of `rxjs`
just choose what you need from this operators I use in this example (`catchError`, `switchMap` or `map`)

```
    this.http.patch('url...').pipe(
    catchError(err => { // catching errors
      
    }),
    switchMap(() => this.http.get()), // switch to another http request
    map(data => {
      // do what you need with the data
      return data
    })
).subscribe()
```